# Get date picker in titanium

Tags: android, datepicker, titanium-mobile

I want to get value in a date picker and add to textfield_date..I used code as follow..It worked well but it's display : Wed Feb 01 2012... but I want to display: 01/04/2012 how must i change attribute?

```
                var minDate = new Date();
                minDate.setFullYear(2012);
                minDate.setMonth(0);
                minDate.setDate(1);

                var maxDate = new Date();
                maxDate.setFullYear(2012);
                maxDate.setMonth(11);
                maxDate.setDate(31);

                var value = new Date();
                value.setFullYear(2012);                    
                value.setMonth(0);
                value.setDate(1);

                var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
                type:Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,
                minDate:minDate,
                maxDate:maxDate,
                value:value
                });

                picker.addEventListener('change',function(e)
                {
                    textfield_date.value = e.value.toLocaleString();
                });
```

Comment: Feb correponds to 02 not 04 :D, see answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
picker.addEventListener('change',function(e){
    var pickerdate = e.value;
    var day = pickerdate.getDate();
    var month = pickerdate.getMonth();
    var year = pickerdate.getFullYear();
    var newdate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year ;
});
```